# Accessing a Rails app that runs in a docker container listening to a port different from 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I want to run a Rails application in a Docker container and access it from a browser by `localhost:3000`, while the Rails application running in a container listens to the port 3001.

#### Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Docker version: 18.09.3, build 774a1f4

#### I do the following.

1) I create a docker compose file and build it.

```
FROM ruby:2.6.1-slim
LABEL maintainer = "Foo Bar foo@bar.com"

RUN apt-get update
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
# Install necessary tools
RUN apt-get install -y vim && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    apt-get install -y bash-completion && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev

RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem install nokogiri
RUN gem install rails
RUN mkdir -p /projects
WORKDIR /projects
```

2) I create a container by running
`docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3001 -v /path/to/my/projects:/projects rails /bin/bash`

`docker ps` gives the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2a8e30016a87        rails               "/bin/bash"         4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3001/tcp   serene_turing
```

3) In my container from my Rails application folder I run
`bundle && rails s -p 3001` and get

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3001
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I enter `localhost:3000` in my browser I get

```
This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.
Try:
   * Checking the connection
   * Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Any idea what is wrong?

By the way, with

`docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -v /path/to/my/projects:/projects rails /bin/bash`

and

`bundle && rails s`

everything works fine.

Comment: Can you try to verify that you can access the rails server from inside the container?

Comment: @JackGore I run `docker exec` and from inside the container I ran `curl localhost:3001`. It works, responds.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks. It was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a connection reset from `localhost:3000` because Puma server is bind to `127.0.0.1` inside the container itself as the log says:

```
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3001
```

So you need to make it allow from any interface which means to make it listen on `0.0.0.0` so you can access it externally. Try to change the `rails s` command to the following:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! By 0.0.0.0 we probably mean "make it accessible from any outside host", don't we?

Comment: It means accessible from any interface attached to server or container in your case so localhost / Ethernet / private network